# sql server and c# with database (the command always give me -1)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

When I execute this query:

```
select ID_UTENTI from USERS where USERNAME_UTENTI='davide'
```

it gives me the correct result that is 2.
But when i execute it in c# it gives me always -1:

```
SqlCommand selectcurrentuser = new SqlCommand("select ID_UTENTI from USERS where USERNAME_UTENTI='"+user_name+"'",con);     
int currentuserid = selectcurrentuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I already tried to replace "user_name" (that is a name of a string) with the username in the table but it gives me -1 in this case too.

Comment: [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx): "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.... For all other types of statements, the return value is -1". I suspect you wanted `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Using ExecuteNonQuery is intended for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery - is not for returning data from the db, its for things like deletes..

Comment: Fun Fact: You defined a select QUERY and you call Method `Execute Non QUERY`which is NOT designed for QUERY. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should change

```
selectcurrentuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to

```
selectcurrentuser.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: thanks, it works! , but what's the difference between ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteScalar?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ) return numbers of affected rows, ExecuteScalar (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx ) - return only 1 item as result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()`  returns the number of rows affected by an update / insert statement.

In your case your are trying to read a value, use `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteReader()` methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

first it's always better to user sql parameters instead of inline values in sql query (look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info)

second try to use sql data reader and execute reader command instead of ExecuteNonQuery.(look [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04))

good luck